# Telegram API: Bad Request: chat_id is empty

Tags: php, api, telegram, telegram-bot

I am working with this lib https://github.com/Eleirbag89/TelegramBotPHP
I had used example code. Have no problem with second one with getUpdates.
But when i am using first one method (Telegram class setWebhook method).
Code:

```
$telegram = new Telegram('YOUR TELEGRAM TOKEN HERE');

$chat_id = $telegram->ChatID();
$content = array('chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => 'Test');
$telegram->sendMessage($content);
```

Error log: Bad Request: chat_id is empty.